# UISplitViewController - Is there a way to autorotate without custom implementation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

My program uses a UISplitViewController as the root view controller.  In order to get the split-view to autorotate when the device orientation changes I need to subclass UISplitViewController and have it return YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Is there a way to have the standard, ie generic UISplitViewController, autorotate?  It seems silly to have to write an entire new subclass just to support orientation changes...

Thanks!
- Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISplitViewController` will rotate automatically as long as both of it's child view controllers return `YES` from `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

Comment: Thanks Mark! -- one other question.  What about if the master view controller is a navigation controller? Does the same thing apply?  Meaning, if the root view controller of the navigation controller returns yes to -shoudlAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation: then will the generic navigation controller autorotate and therefor the splitView will as well?

Comment: Yes. In order for a `UINavigationController` to auto rotate, all of it's child view controllers must also return `YES` from `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`. This also applies to `UITabBarController` as it is a container view controller.